# Numpy/Numba much slower with newest version of anaconda

Tags: python, numpy, performance, numba

I've been using anaconda version 07/2020 for some time and just yesterday i decided to upgrade every package and python to the newest versions.

To my immense surprise, most numba functions i had got much slower, alongside some python functions

Example:

```
x = np.linspace(0,5,10001)
y = 2*x
@njit(fastmath=True)
def partial_1dproblem_BFDM_3(var,var2): #First derivative
    y = var
    x = var2
    dx = x[1] - x[2]
    dydx = np.empty(y.shape)
    vardim = var.ndim
    invalid_input = 0
    
    
    #Forward
    
    if vardim == 1:
        
        i=0
        dydx[i] = (-3* y[i]  +  4* y[i+1] - y[i+2])/(2*dx)
        
        i = 1
        dydx[i] = (y[i] - y[i-1])/(dx)
        
        i = 2
        dydx[i] = (y[i-2] - 4* y[i-1] + 3*y[i])/(2*dx)
        
        for i in range(3,len(dydx)):
            dydx[i] = (11*y[i] -18*y[i-1] + 9*y[i-2] -2*y[i-3])/(6*dx)
                                             
    else:
        invalid_input = 1
                        
    if invalid_input == 1:
        raise ValueError('Invalid Input')                
    else:
        return dydx 


partial_1dproblem_BFDM_3(y,x)

%timeit partial_1dproblem_BFDM_3(y,x)
```

On anaconda package version 07/2020(numba 0.50.1) this function runs at:

- 6.07 µs ± 47.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

On the newest anaconda package 03/2023(numba 0.56.4) this function runs at

- 21.9 µs ± 31.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

A huge slowdown! Also, i decided to test even older versions and there are wild differences for pure numpy functions like

```
def fexp(x):
    y = np.exp(x)
    return y
```

Using the same array above, on the anaconda 10/19(numpy 1.16.6) it runs at 10 µs while in the 07/2020(numpy 1.17.0) it runs at 50 µs! What is happening here?

Comment: maybe numpy changed something that breaks some optimization in numba and numba needs time to "catch-up". I think this question should be asked at numba github

Comment: It is very likely this issue: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/8172#issuecomment-1160474583 It should work better with 0.57. (0.53 until 0.57 had this issue)